# Can we unify 3 different First Order Logic sets/expressions?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, artificial-intelligence, unification

Wherever I searched about unification in first-order logic (FOL) expressions, I could only find it as the unification of "**two** different logical atomic expressions identical by finding a substitution". So, I want to ask if it is possible to unify 3 different sets of FOLs.

For eg: Expression ***{p(b, X, f(g(Z)))*** and ***p(Z, f(Y), f(Y))}*** can be unified into ***{ p(b, f(g(b)), f(g(b)); p(b, f(g(b)), f(g(b))}*** and the Most General Unifier(MGU) would be ***{ b/Z, f(Y) /X, g(b) /Y}***.

But if we add a 3rd term to the expression, say  {(, (), ), ((), (),), (, (), )}, can we unify the FOLs? If yes, what would be the MGU?

Comment: I am tempted to turn the question into another one with a "what would it be good for" ? Because, beeing assumed that a triple unification exists, it would be of no use because it can be replaced by a two-steps classical unification.

Comment: wouldn't it shorten the algorithmic process if we could actually unify 3 FOLs or even more at once, rather than unifying only 2 at once?